# What is the purpose of the plus '+' in a parameter?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I have a function with a parameter:`setTimeout("progressBar("+val+")",300);`. Why must I add + beside `val` so that it becomes `+val+`?

Context the the function call:

```
function progressBar(val){
    var pro_bar = document.getElementById("progress_bar");
    var stat = document.getElementById("status");
    stat.innerHTML = val + "%";
    pro_bar.value = val;
    val++;
    var load = setTimeout("progressBar("+val+")",300);
        if(val == 100){
            stat.innerHTML = "100%";
            pro_bar.value = 100;
            clearTimeout(load);
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Process Complete";
        }
    }       
    var initial_value = 0;
    progressBar(initial_value);
```

Comment: It is simply for concatenation. In your case, the val is a variable. So, if you avoid the + inside the double quotes, the val is treated as a string instead of variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` in JavaScript can be used for string concatenation.

e.g.

- `"This " + "That"` Result: `"This That"` (Two strings joined together)
- `"This " + 1` Result: `"This 1"` (The int will be converted to a string and joined)
- `var varName = "A value"; "This " + varName` Result: `"This A value"` (The value of the variable will be added to the string)

In the case you posted, the string will be cause `progressBar()` to be called with the variable called `val` passed in.

Comment: It's the same thing, just with multiple strings. e.g. `"1" + "2" + "3"` the second `+` is just adding the `")"` in your example.